# How to update radio options through Ajax in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am trying to update a list of radio options depending on the `person` that a `user` selects in a form.

_fields.html.erb:

```
<%= f.label :person %>
<%= f.select(:person_id, current_user.person_names) %>

<%= f.label :invoice_type %>
<%= radio_buttons_collection(f.object.invoice_types, f) %>
```

---

application_helper.rb:

```
def radio_buttons_collection(types, f) # works, but not with Ajax!
  types_html = types.map do |type|
    f.radio_button(:invoice_type, type)
  end
  safe_join(types_html)
end
```

---

projects_controller.rb:

```
def get_invoice_types
  person = Person.find(params[:person_id])  
  @types = person.address_types
end
```

get_invoice_types.js.erb:

```
$('#project_invoice_type').html("<%= escape_javascript(radio_buttons_collection(@types, f)) %>");
```

---

application.js:

```
$("#project_person_id").change(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: '/projects/get_invoice_types',
    data: 'person_id=' + this.value,
    dataType: 'script'
  })
});
```

Everything works except that the radio options won't get updated when the `person` gets changed in the form.

Can anybody tell me how to do this?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: looks like form object in ajax is nil. Can you please check that form object i.e. f in get_invoice_types.js.erb is nil or not ?

Comment: Thanks for your help. Silly n00b question, but how exactly can I check that `f` is not nil?

Comment: you can try to print in application_hlper method. which should be call.

Comment: The problem is that the `radio_buttons_collection(types, f)` method doesn't get updated at all through Ajax. So I can't really test the output here.

Comment: Can you please paste form code ?

Comment: OK, I added two more lines to the form code above. Those four lines are the ones that matter I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will suggest not to pass form object to helper method

```
def radio_buttons_collection(types, invoice_type)
  types_html = types.map do |type|
    radio_button_tag("project[invoice_type]", type, type == invoice_type)
  end
  safe_join(types_html)
end
```

pass invoice_type to helper method along with types.

in controller define

```
@invoice_type = person.invoice_type
```

get_invoice_types.js.erb:

```
$('#project_invoice_type').html("<%= escape_javascript(radio_buttons_collection(@types, @invoice_type)) %>");
```

_fields.html.erb:

```
<%= f.label :invoice_type %>
<div id = 'project_invoice_type'>
  <%= radio_buttons_collection(f.object.invoice_types, f.object.invoice_type) %>
</div>
```

Comment: OK, tried that, even with `project[invoice_type]` instead of `form[invoice_type]`. But it seems there's no interaction with the database when doing it this way. Nothing gets saved.

Comment: check params in server logs . is invoice_type present in params ?

Comment: Yes, it is there: `"invoice_type"=>"business"`. It gets saved to the database as well. But in the form it never gets displayed. The radio buttons are always empty.

Comment: OK, thanks. The values get saved to the database now. But the available radio buttons don't change when the `person` gets changed using the select box. There should be either one or two radio buttons to choose from, depending on the selected `person`.

Comment: add a div container to radio buttons which will be replaced by ajax request , as i did in new edit

Comment: I tried that as well but I am getting a `MissingTemplate` error now: `Missing template projects/get_invoice_types, application/get_invoice_types with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder]}` Maybe I should have a look at this tomorrow again with fresh eyes.

Comment: Hello again, turns out my `get_invoice_types.erb.js` was the cause of all the misery. I had lines 1 and 2 commented out temporarily using double slashes (`//`) which commented out the code for TextMate (my code editor) but seemingly not for Rails. Thanks for your help again, though. I'll mark your answer as correct since I would have been lost without you on this one. Cheers!

Comment: Good to hear that you Finally made it :) Happy Coding

Answer (score 0):

You need to trigger the change.  Try this in your get_invoice_types.js.erb

```
$('#project_invoice_type').html("<%= escape_javascript(radio_buttons_collection(@types, f)) %>");
$('#project_invoice_type').trigger('change');
```

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in your rails server logs?  Any javascript errors popping up when inspecting?

Comment: Yes! I am getting an `Internal Server Error` there in `app/views/projects/get_invoice_types.js.erb:1`. The raw HTML looks a bit ugly: `undefined local variable or method f&#x27; for #&lt;#&lt;Class:0x007f9739358b80&gt;:0x007f973bdf0118&gt;`. I guess it's trying to say that the local variable `f` is not there.